# Maximal compactifications without the Tychonoff theorem

Tags: general-topology

I once saw a neat proof in American Mathematical Monthly of the Tychonoff theorem (The Tychonoff product topology of a family of compact spaces is compact) for the special case of the product of compact Hausdorff spaces, using maximal compactifications. However the only development of the theory of compactifications of Tychonoff spaces that I am familiar with, uses this special case of the Tychonoff theorem at the outset.That is, if $S$ is a Tychonoff space with weight $K$ then $S$ is equal, up to homeomorphism, to a subspace of $I^K$ , the product space of $K$ copies of $I=[0,1]$ with the Tychonoff product topology. Hence we know that a compactification of $S$ exists : the closure  $Cl(S)$  of $S$ in $I^K$. But here we need to know that $I^K$ is compact (as well as Hausdorff, which is elementary) to know that $Cl(S)$ is compact. $$QUESTION $$  Can the basics of the theory of maximal compactifications of Tychonoff spaces be developed without using the Tychonoff theorem?

Comment: A crucial property that the construction of the Stone–Čech compactification (or a maximal compactification of a Tychonoff space homeomorphic to the Stone–Čech compactification) exploits is that $[0,1]^K$ is compact. While I’m not a topologist, I doubt that you can prove the compactness of that space without reference to, or without using a proof essentially mimicking, Tychonoff’s theorem. Keep in mind also that Tychonoff’s theorem and the axiom of choice are logically equivalent in Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory, so rejecting Tychonoff’s theorem leads us to dangerous waters...

Comment: I always assume AC unless forced not to. It was a nice proof in AMM. Too bad it may be circular.

Comment: Can you give a reference?

Comment: You could use ultrafilters to give a direct definition, I think.

Comment: Could be. There is an analog of the Worrall extension for a non-normal Tychonoff space  $S$, that gives  $\beta S$ but I can't recall it.

Comment: Tíkhonov's theorem for Hausdorff spaces is strictly weaker than the axiom of choice (it is equivalent to the [ultrafilter lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_prime_ideal_theorem#The_ultrafilter_lemma)), what is equivalent to full choice is the theorem for products of quasicompact spaces.

Comment: @triple_sec  The article's title may have been "Life Without $T_2$" and the year was approx. 1972 .

Comment: @user254665 Do you have a link to *Worrall extension*, do you mean *Wallman* (rather than Worrall) compactification: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallman_compactification and http://www.jstor.org/stable/2037221, and http://projects.lsv.ens-cachan.fr/topology/?page_id=374 It is also discussed in Engelking's General Topology book

Comment: @Mirko . Sorry. I did mean Wallman extension, not Worrall. I have Engelking's book.