# Relation between universal properties and topological invariants.

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, product-space, universal-property

I don't really have any experience working with universal maps or adjoint functors (well, neither with categories, really. Only some basic definitions and intuitions). However, I have the feeling that maybe it's not a crazy idea to think of multiplicative properties in topology as *topological invariants preserved when formal categorical products (or coproducts, or quotients... ) are done*. I guess this topological products, coproducts and quotients have to do with universal maps, that's why I picked that title for my question, but I don't know how to apply this language yet so I'm sorry in advance for any possible misunderstanding.

Is it possible to achieve some statement like "Because of these *categorical properties* of compactness, compactness is a multiplicative property"?

Comment: So you're asking for an abstract nonsense proof of Tychonoff's theorem? As I see it, the problem lies with the *categorical properties of compactness* part. I don't know of any categorical characterisations of compactness.

Comment: @Tyrone maybe. It happens, for example, that any separation axiom and countability axiom are multiplicative and additive. What makes them special categorically speaking so they are preserved in that way? Has it anything to do with categories at all? Perhaps, if there is a way of characterizing these properties, we could explain why they behave the same when it comes to universal maps. I'm really guessing, I hope that this vague intuition make sense to you. Thanks!

Comment: The forgetful functor from compact Hausdorff spaces to topological spaces has a left adjoint, the Stone-Cech compactification, so it preserves all (categorical) limits, in particular products. This does not quite give Tychonoff's theorem because we need to restrict to compact Hausdorff spaces and because we need to show that (categorical) products exist in compact Hausdorff spaces. But it's a start.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan yes, I think that's exactly where I'm going. Do you think anything more accurate could be achieved with this approach?

Comment: (Hmm also the argument might be circular; at least one approach to constructing the Stone-Cech compactification might require Tychonoff's theorem to prove compactness...)

Comment: Joel, there are many separation axioms that are not productive. Countability is even worse, and is often not even coproductive.

Comment: @Tyrone you are right, thank you. I forgot that important detail while making the point. The thing is that many of them (T0 to T3 1/2) are productive and coproductive, for example.

Comment: Here is a thought which doesn't answer your question. If $\mathcal{E}$ is a class of spaces, then the epireflective hull in $Top$ of $\mathcal{E}$ is the full subcategory consisting of all subspaces of all products of spaces in $\mathcal{E}$. Thus for instance $Haus$ is epireflective in $Top$, because is is productive and hereditary. Compactness is not hereditary, so does not give you an epireflective category.

Comment: On the other hand, if $\mathcal{E}\subseteq Haus$, then the epireflective hull of $\mathcal{E}$ in $Haus$ is the full subcategory consisting of all *closed* subspaces of products in $\mathcal{E}$. Thus it is true that $CompHaus$ is epireflective in $Haus$.

Comment: My point kind of is that in each case we arrive at an intersting categorical statement about the structure of $Top$, not by abstract reasoning, but by doing topology. i.e. the interesting implication is pointing in the opposite direction of what you are asking for. Having said that, I am interested to see a good answer to your question (I've upvoted).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan. This Q and its comments may reflect on your comment. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1420110/maximal-compactifications-without-the-tychonoff-theorem

Comment: "Multiplicative properties" of topology?

Comment: @FShrike what I meant back then with multiplicative properties are the topological invariants that are preserved by cartesian product. For example, compactness, because the usual topological product of compact topological spaces is again compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is a question that I made two years ago, I just realised after discussing it with a collegue that this question is a particular case to something that every mathematician is constantly trying to answer: "do these two things commute?"

That was, at least, what I intended to understand with this question, although I did not know it back then.

In any case, asking for a categorical characterization of a topological property that would let us completely understand its behavior with respect to the usual operators of set theory or algebra is like asking for "a general solution" to Category Theory.

Realising this, at least for me, answers the question.

Comment: Category theory concerns itself with many things not strictly about topological properties. I don't understand this 'realisation'

Comment: @FShrike Elemental topology is just the subject in which my question arose, but I claim it is a particular case to a question too general to be answered.